# how to print all elements in an array

Tags: php, arrays

How can I solve this question:

> Write a loop to display all elements of array and result is (3, 17, 2.8, 1.8).

I did something like this, but it seems not to work:

```
<php?
    $numbers = array(3, 17, 2.8, 1.8);

    for($x = 0) {
       echo $numbers[$x];
       $x++
    }
?>
```

Comment: Btw: google is your friend in development, you probably need 2 seconds to google this :) - Think about your code aswell, how does for($x = 0) Would make sense if you thinik about it? :P

Comment: Reading the docs always helps. Syntax of a [for() loop](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) shows three "arguments", not one; together with plenty of examples as well

Comment: Make sure the start of your code starts with `<?php` instead of `<php?`

Comment: I don't know if just a typo or an actual error on your part. But the opening php tag is `<?php` not `<php?`

Comment: Dear all, please leave the code of the OP untouched unless he himself states he made some copy-paste mistake. Especially don't modify it if your modification isn't actually correct.

Comment: `array_walk($numbers, function($number, $index) { printf("The number at point %s is: %s" . PHP_EOL, $index, $number); }` for the lulz

Comment: @panther: if you see a syntax error in code, please *do not* edit it out. Doing so will mean the question no longer makes sense, since the problem has been silently removed. Please point it out in comments instead.

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $numbers = array(3, 17, 2.8, 1.8);
    foreach($numbers as $number)
        echo $number."<br />";

?>
```

If you want to use a for loop:

```
<?php

    $numbers = array(3, 17, 2.8, 1.8);
    for($count = 0; $count < count($numbers); $count++)
        echo $numbers[$count] ."<br />";

?>
```

Output:

```
3
17
2.8
1.8
```

For further information about `foreach` loop see: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Remove the `<br />` or change the output to `3<br />` etc. to reflect the actual output required

Answer (score 1):

using `foreach` loop

```
    $numbers = array(3, 17, 2.8, 1.8);

    foreach($numbers as $n) 
    {
        echo $n;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use foreach instead:

```
$numbers = array(3, 17, 2.8, 1.8);
foreach($numbers as $number) {
    echo $number."<br />";
}
```

Using `for` it should be:

```
for ($x = 0; $x < count($numbers); $x++) {
   echo $numbers[$x] . '<br>';
}
```